# How to structure repsonse of nested object query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb schema looks like this

```
"detail": {
    "EN": {
      "title": "Paper Distributation",
      "jobDescription": "share papers to everyonre",
      "brandDescription": "DMart"
    },
    "HI": {
      "title": "Paper Distributation in different language",
      "jobDescription": "share papers to everyonre in different language",
      "brandDescription": "DMart in different language"
    }
}
```

and i want response like this from query with passing any language like **EN** or **HI**

```
"detail": {   
      "title": "Paper Distributation",
      "jobDescription": "share papers to everyonre",
      "brandDescription": "DMart"
 }
```

how can i achieve this please help me with this
Thank you

I tried to access it with projection like `detail.EN:1` but not getting proper required response

Comment: `"detail": "$detail.EN"` [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pHE8TgDpSZa)

Comment: Yes It's working but without aggregation is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it also works without aggregation. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJgMOoHbwKb)